# Export Import Full Database

Tags: oracle, import, export

I have two computers. operating system: windows 7 in both, oracle 11g in both

I have created a database in computer 1. and created dumpfile using export utility

```
expdp usersname/password directory=dir dumpfile=full.dmp full=y
```

now i  have transaferd the dump file & log file in another computer.
when i am running command

```
impdp username/password directory=dir dumpfile=full.dmp
```

I got the following errors:

> ORA-39002: invalid operation.
>   ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
>   ORA-29283: invalid file operation.
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536.
>   ORA-29283: invalid file operation

Comment: Do you have directory object in another database in another computer?

Comment: make sure the database directory (not only physical directory on the machine ) do exist in the other system and provide the read and write grant to schema on which you are importing the data

Comment: impdp command completed by showing this message

Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 7906 error(s) at 13:09:49